# Instagram feeds using tag name of particular user

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, feed

I am trying to fetch the instagram feeds to my site using tag name.
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
above is the api which I am using to get the feeds.

Now the feeds are displaying from all the users who use the tag. I need to restrict the feeds for the particular user who use the tag name.

Anyone come across this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of the Instagram Api does not have an endpoint that will allow you to get media by `tag-name` **AND** `user-id`. Your best bet is to use 1 of the following endpoints, and then loop through the results and filter out the media that matches the 2nd condition.

1. Search for posts by given hashtag's name using GET `/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent` API endpoint request and then filter the response list of media to match the `user-id` for the particular user in question.
   or
2. Search for posts by the particular user using GET `/users/{user-id}/media/recent` API endpoint request and then manually check every post if its tags array contains the specific hashtag you are looking for.

I recommend you go with option 2 as that will be faster, since an individual user feed is a much smaller data set than media from 1000s of Instagram users tagged with a hashtag.